# on select a href change color in ul li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I use tab menu for select different tab i want to change the color of selected button, when I select button change it color

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#" name="tab1">Tempu Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="tab2">Buy and Sale</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="tab2">Job Service</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and my css id 
and my JavaScript is

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
    $("#tabs ul  li a").click(function () {
        $("#tabs ul li a").not(this).removeClass("active").addClass('unactive')
        $(this).toggleClass("unactive").toggleClass("active");
    });
});//]]>
</script>
```

i also use this script for this

```
        <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contenty").find("[id^='tab']").hide(); 
    $("#tabs li:first").attr("id","currenty"); 
    $("#contenty #tab1").fadeIn(); 

    $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).closest("li").attr("id") == "currenty"){ 
         return;       
        }
        else{             
          $("#contenty").find("[id^='tab']").hide(); 
          $("#tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
          $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); 
          $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

and i use jquery 1.9.1

Comment: What is the problem? looks like it works fine.

Comment: yes its look fine but not working....

Comment: Is this what your expected result ? http://jsfiddle.net/3XU4e/

Comment: Check out the most minimal approach below. and why is downvote here?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#tabs ul  li a").click(function () {
     $('#tabs ul  li a.active').removeClass('active').addClass('unactive');
     $(this).addClass('active');
   });
});
```

Try wrapping the code in ready event handler instead of load.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$("#tabs ul  li a").click(function () {
    $("#tabs ul li a").removeClass("active").addClass('unactive')
    $(this).toggleClass("active unactive");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L3Pmh/)

Answer (score 0):

The most minimal approach would be,

```
$("#tabs ul  li a").click(function () {
    var active_link = $("#tabs ul li a").filter('.active').removeClass('active'); // filter elements only with class active and remove it.
    $(this).toggleClass("active"); // toggle active class of this element
});
```

### <kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L3Pmh/1/)</kbd>